# How to show less column in an asp.net gridview/listview when browser come from a mobile device?

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net Listview that show (for instance) 10 columns. From a desktop browser point of view, there isn't any problem. 
But i would like to allow my users to see same Listview with less columns when they browse my website from a mobile desktop (tablet/iphone etc.).

Is it possible to programmaticaly check this ?

I think, for example, to create 2 listview, and via server side code, check browser/screen resolution, then hide and show the correct listview...

Answer (score 0):

You can check for User Agent in http request.

```
var userAgent = Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();
```

You can use the function below

```
  protected override void Page_Load(EventArgs e) 
  { 

        string userAgent = Request.UserAgent; 
        if (userAgent.Contains("BlackBerry") 
          || (userAgent.Contains("iPhone") || (userAgent.Contains("Android")))) 
        { 
            //hide the column here

        }       
    }
```